# The priority_queue of STL in c++

Tags: c++, stl, priority-queue

I want to construct two priority queue that has different compare method(there are two reverse priority methods named cmp1 and cmp2)
My program can't go through the compiler check.Why does such error happen and is there any better solution?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

struct item
{
    string name;
    string sex;
    string id;
    double score;
    friend istream& operator >> (istream &is,item& data)
    {
        is>>data.name>>data.sex>>data.id>>data.score;
    }
    /*friend bool operator < (item& a,item& b)
    {
        return a.score<b.score;
    }*/
};

struct cmp1{
    operator bool()(item& x,item& y)
    {
        return x.score>y.score;
    }
};
struct cmp2
{
    operator bool()(item& x,item& y)
    {
        return x.score<y.score;
    }
};
int main()
{
    priority_queue<item,vector<item>,cmp1> boys;
    priority_queue<item,vector<item>,cmp2>girls;
    item temp;
    int num;
    cin>>num>>temp;
    for(int i=0;i<num;i++)
    {
        if(temp.sex=="M")
            boys.push(temp);
        else
            girls.push(temp);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should show the error that you're getting so that people can help you more easily.

Comment: At least, should be `operator bool()(const item& x, const item& y)`

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to take a wild guess at the problem.... your comparison functors are incorrect. Instead of overloading `operator bool`, you need to overload the function call operator, i.e.

```
struct cmp1{
    bool operator()(const item& x, const item& y)
    {
        return x.score>y.score;
    }
};

struct cmp2
{
    bool operator()(const item& x, const item& y)
    {
       return x.score<y.score;
    }
};
```

(Perhaps this was what you intended, but just got the syntax a little wrong?)

Comment: @abyss.7 I didn't see your comment -- looking at the timestamps, I was probably typing this when you submitted it. No theft intended! Obviously great minds think alike :-)

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I think the best way to do it is to use std::less and std::greater. If you have overloaded operator< and operator> for your class, you can do it like this:

```
std::priority_queue<item, std::vector<item>, std::greater<item>> boys;
std::priority_queue<item, std::vector<item>, std::less<item>> girls;
```

That way you don't have to write the functor. Don't forget to `#include <functional>`.

Also, don't forget that the operators have to be overloaded taking const ref arguments (you can also take them by value, but that's not usually a good idea), and as const methods, like in:

```
bool operator<(const item& i) const {
    return value < i.value;
}
bool operator>(const item& i) const {
    return value > i.value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your operator functions to this:

```
struct cmp1{
  bool operator()(item& x,item& y)
  {
    return x.score>y.score;
  }
};
struct cmp2
{
  bool operator()(item& x,item& y)
  {
    return x.score<y.score;
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You have defined the methods in the comparison classes wrong.

Try the following code:

```
struct cmp1{
    bool operator()(item& x,item& y)
    {
        return x.score>y.score;
    }
};
```

You have defined the methods as `operator bool() ...`.

Also it is nice to add `const` to the parameters, as `const item& x` for showing that you won't change their values, as well a const at the end of the function definition:

```
bool operator()(const item& x, const item& y) const {...}
```

for showing that you won't change the member fields too.

Answer (score 0):

I will write the third correct version of the predcate

```
struct cmp1
{
    bool operator()( const item &x, const item &y ) const
    {
        return x.score > y.score;
    }
};

struct cmp2
{
    bool operator()( const item &x, const item &y ) const
    {
       return x.score < y.score;
    }
};
```